# Fastest way of computing powerset of an array using Numpy/Scikit-Learn

Tags: python, numpy, math, scikit-learn, numpy-ndarray

I want to calculate powerset of 1-dim array using numpy, sckit-learn of whatever is the fastest approach.
By fast approach i mean, something that will take less that 9 seconds, even when the length of the input is 10000.

This code below does the trick. But it is too slow.

```py
from itertools import chain, combinations
import numpy as np

def powerset(iterable):
    "powerset([1,2,3]) --> () (1,) (2,) (3,) (1,2) (1,3) (2,3) (1,2,3)"
    s = iterable
    comb_iter = chain.from_iterable(combinations(s, i) for i in range(len(s)+1))
    return list(comb_iter)
```

I have tried multiple solutions from the internet, but nothing seems to be working for me as my time limitation is a critical constraint.

Comment: In the given code, converting comb_iter to list is taking too much time. I think even if someone can suggest me an alternative to that using numpy would also be a great progress for me. Thanks

Comment: For input length 200000 result size is 2^200000, so I doubt we can live so long to see it...

Comment: @MBo, what about 10,000?

Comment: Practically impossible for 100.

Comment: Run the following program to see approximately how many steps 2^10000 is: `print(2**10000)`.

Comment: Why do you need the powerset?

Comment: @DaniMesejo, I just want to compute all possible combinations of a list..... This applies to many use cases.